# What's the difference between set-macro-character and set-dispatch-macro-character?

Tags: common-lisp, reader-macro

From the signatures of these functions, the obvious difference is that `set-macro-character` allows you to set reader macro function for a single character, and `set-dispatch-macro-character` allows you to set it for any combination of two characters. Is this the only difference? When do I need to use one instead of another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`set-macro-character`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set_ma.htm) governs
reading objects marked with a *single* special character, e.g.,

- [lists](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_da.htm) `(...)`
- [comments](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dd.htm) `; ...`

[`set-dispatch-macro-character`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set__1.htm)
governs reading objects marked with *two* (or more) characters, e.g.,

- [vectors](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhc.htm) `#(...)`
- [arrays](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhl.htm) `#A(...)`
- [structures](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhm.htm) `#S(...)`

See

- [2.1.4.4 Macro Characters](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_add.htm)
- [2.4 Standard Macro Characters](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_d.htm)
- [2.4.8 Sharpsign](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dh.htm)

Comment: So, the only difference is that first one allows you to bind reader macro to only a single character, and second one to 2+ characters?

Comment: Yes, this is the difference.